# how to unwrap as string the value that I receive in XML

Tags: objective-c, xml, parsing

I am recieving a value from server in XML like:

```
 if ([_caller_id stringValue]){

        NSLog(@"the caller Id is %ld", (long)[_caller_id intValue]);

    }
```

what I want is, to unwrap it as NSString and I tried with stringValue but It doesn't work. Any help Appreciate.

Comment: Why you don't use any XML parsers?

Comment: For now, I can not,..